# How to iterate over an array of objects Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, class, object

I created a class and added objects like so:

```
class Tops
  def initialize(neckline, brand, maincolour, style)
    @neckline = neckline
    @brand = brand
    @maincolour = maincolour
    @style = style
  end
end

top1 = Tops.new("Sweetheart", "Miss Selfridge", "Blue", "Bardot")
top2 = Tops.new("Scoop", "Target", "Pink", "Vest")
top3 = Tops.new("Boat", "Unknown", "Red", "Tank")
```

I then used the `push` method to add some of these objects into an empty array.

```
currentTopChoices = []
currentTopChoices.push(top1,top3)
```

I then used some the `each` method to run a block of code or each object in this array

```
currentTopChoices.each { |x| puts @neckline }
```

So my aim was really to get an output of each neckline of the objects in the array but I get an output of:

```
Boat
Boat
```

When I really wanted:

```
Sweetheart
Boat
```

Which is really the neckline of the last object but printed twice. I get no error messages so what exactly am I missing here?

Comment: just make a setter or  add a `attr_accessor` then use `map` for the new array.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Since `@neckline` is un-initialized, it should evaluate to `nil` and thus print two empty lines, not `Boat`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adding an `attr_accessor` to `Tops` (which will provide a `Top#neckline` accessor method), you can use `Array#map` or (its alias `Array#collect`) to build a collection of `necklines`:

```
class Tops
  attr_accessor :neckline

  def initialize(neckline, brand, maincolour, style)
    @neckline = neckline
    @brand = brand
    @maincolour = maincolour
    @style = style
  end
end

top1 = Tops.new("Sweetheart", "Miss Selfridge", "Blue", "Bardot")
top2 = Tops.new("Scoop", "Target", "Pink", "Vest")
top3 = Tops.new("Boat", "Unknown", "Red", "Tank")

[top1, top3].map(&:neckline) # => ["Sweetheart", "Boat"]
# or, more explicitly
[top1, top3].map { |top| top.neckline } # => ["Sweetheart", "Boat"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that somehow you are confusing yourself by either not showing all your code, or maybe running this in irb, where at some point you had a statement like?

```
@neckline = "Boat"
```

For example the code you posted, if placed directly in a *file_name.rb* like so:

```
class Tops
  def initialize(neckline, brand, maincolour, style)
    @neckline = neckline
    @brand = brand
    @maincolour = maincolour
    @style = style
  end
end

top1 = Tops.new("Sweetheart", "Miss Selfridge", "Blue", "Bardot")
top2 = Tops.new("Scoop", "Target", "Pink", "Vest")
top3 = Tops.new("Boat", "Unknown", "Red", "Tank")

currentTopChoices = []
currentTopChoices.push(top1,top3)

currentTopChoices.each { |x| puts @neckline }
```

and then run using ruby *file_name.rb*

would just produce 2 blank lines because `@neckline` is not define at this scope (toplevel), so it's value is nil

To get this to work the way you intend you can add

```
attr_reader :neckline
```

and then refer to `x.neckline` within the block you pass to each, since `x` will take one the value of each of the `Tops` objects in `currentTopChoices`

note: `attr_accessor` adds both a setter and a getter for neckline, if you only need read access to that property than that's all you should allow (which is what you get with `attr_reader` ), if you **really** need to both get **and set** the value of neckline on an instance after creating it then `att_accessor` would make sense.

Here is an updated version of your code that should behave as you are expecting.

```
class Tops
  attr_reader :neckline  # added to allow read access to @neckline
  def initialize(neckline, brand, maincolour, style)
    @neckline = neckline
    @brand = brand
    @maincolour = maincolour
    @style = style
  end
end

top1 = Tops.new("Sweetheart", "Miss Selfridge", "Blue", "Bardot")
top2 = Tops.new("Scoop", "Target", "Pink", "Vest")
top3 = Tops.new("Boat", "Unknown", "Red", "Tank")

currentTopChoices = []
currentTopChoices.push(top1,top3)

currentTopChoices.each { |x| puts x.neckline }  # access the neckline property for each element
```